# How to run roscore and then run a package on system startup.?

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys.
I am new to ROS. I wan to run following on the system start up:

1. Roscore
2. ROS Package
3. ROS bag record.

Although i have searched on google and many people have answered this already, but i couldnt understand it, so if any one could help me in a kindergarten teacher way..
Also any suggestion for a good book/blog etc related to linux and ROS, for dummies and new comers like me...
Your help would be really appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255576/how-to-run-roscore-and-then-run-a-package-on-system-startup.?/) by [UsmanArif](https://answers.ros.org/users/27566/usmanarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-02-25**:
You might want to split this into two questions since they are independent of one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [robot_upstart](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_upstart) to generate a "service" that will run a launch file. Within the launch file you may include your node(s), parameters, bag, etc.

The first step is to get a launch file which does everything you want. Do that before attempting to use robot_upstart and it will dramatically reduce debugging any issues you may have.

---

Originally posted by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) with karma: 300 on 2017-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-02-25**:
Is this still working on 16.04 with systemd?

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-02-25**:
Yes. I am using it with Ubuntu 16.04 on Raspberry Pi for the LoCoRo project.